# iOS: how to fill the pdf Form

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I am looking for a possibility to show a pdf with input fields checkBox  so a user can fill the form and save the pdf. I am getting the pdf file from server and need to submit after filling this

[image]

I already tried some sample-solutions. The best solution I got is ILPDFKit. It does exactly what I want to achieve but unfortunately it is not working with some pdf-versions.
Please help here

Comment: What problem you are facing with ILPDFKit @Ram

Comment: this is not working for all. version of pdf @HarishSingh